# PHP loop through array and just get values in position 0

Tags: php, arrays

I am using PHP. I have an array where I need to loop through it and get all of the values in the [0] position (or strings) of the array and I am completely stumped. I created a function that looped back on its self to try and parse out the elements but is was no good. Is there a simple way to loop through this array and just get the elements that are not arrays so that in the end it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ccrs_date
    [1] => prelim_title_report_date
    [2] => additional_escrow_deposit_date
    [3] => earnest_money_date
    [4] => acceptance_date
    [5] => contract_date
    [6] => prelim_title_report_date
)
```

Here's my original array that I am trying to parse out.

```
Array
(
    [0] => ccrs_date
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => prelim_title_report_date
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => additional_escrow_deposit_date
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => earnest_money_date
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => acceptance_date
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => contract_date
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: you have `prelim_title_report_date` in your desired result three times, is that intended?

Comment: Oops, nope - not intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize a recursive function to retrieve the desired results.

Using the dataset:

```
$v = [
    'ccrs_date',
    [
        'prelim_title_report_date',
        [
            'additional_escrow_deposit_date',
            [
                'earnest_money_date',
                [
                    'acceptance_date',
                    [
                        'contract_date',
                        [
                            'prelim_title_report_date',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/vjERQ

```
function get_zero_index(array $array, &$result = [])
{
    foreach ($array as $i => $v) {
        if ($i === 0 && is_string($v)) {
            $result[] = $v;
        } elseif (is_array($v)) {
            get_zero_index($v, $result);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(get_zero_index($v));
```

Resulting output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ccrs_date
    [1] => prelim_title_report_date
    [2] => additional_escrow_deposit_date
    [3] => earnest_money_date
    [4] => acceptance_date
    [5] => contract_date
    [6] => prelim_title_report_date
)
```

---

Alternatively if you are just wanting to flatten the multi-dimensional array with the first element in the array, you can also use the SPL [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) along with [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

Example: https://3v4l.org/VEJdN

```
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($v));
$result = [];
$d = null;
foreach ($ri as $k => $r) {
    if ($d !== ($cd = $ri->getDepth())) { 
        //ignore items of the same depth as the previous record
        $d = $cd;
        if ($k === 0 && is_scalar($r)) {
            //only retrieve the first record that is scalar
            $result[] = $r;
        }
    }
}    
print_r($result);
```

Instead to fully flatten the multi-dimensional array, you only need to use [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) on the iterator object, with false as the second argument to not preserve the keys.

Example: https://3v4l.org/6Ve93

```
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($v));
print_r(iterator_to_array($ri, false));
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I have spent all day on this - thank you so much!

Comment: @LargeTuna Not a problem, if you are just looking to flatten your array, you can remove the `$i === 0` and change `is_string` to `is_scalar`, which will work with [multiple nested arrays as well](https://3v4l.org/RHlJL).

Comment: @LargeTuna see my updated answer in regard to [PHP Build An Array By Looping Back On Self Until All Records Are Found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49693128/1144627)  e.g Flattening array https://3v4l.org/6Ve93

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this approach?

```
if (!is_array($current_element))
{
    // $current_element must be a string, since it's not an array
    echo $current_element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to fix the underlying problem that caused this array to be like that.

However, to answer your question, you resulting array looks like this:

```php
$arr = ["elem1", ["elem2", ["elem3", ["elem4", ["elem5", ["elem6", [""]]]]]]];
```

You could retrieve all the first elements recursively (i.e. a function calling itself), or iteratively using a loop.

Recursive strategies tend to be neater. However, due to its nature, it also consumes more memory. So for large arrays in PHP, recursive methods are not recommended.

In any case, a recursive function to "flatten" your array would be:

```php
function accumulateFirstElem_rec($arr) {
  if (is_array($arr)) {
    return isset($arr[1]) ? array_merge([$arr[0]], accumulateFirstElem($arr[1])) : [$arr[0]];
  }

  return [];
}
```

While a possible iterative approach would be:

```php
function accumulateFirstElem_iter($arr) {
  $result = [];

  while (true) {
    array_push($result, $arr[0]);

    if (isset($arr[1]) && is_array($arr[1])) {
      $arr = $arr[1];
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Calling `print_r(accumulateFirstElem_iter($arr));` on both functions would return the same result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => elem1
    [1] => elem2
    [2] => elem3
    [3] => elem4
    [4] => elem5
    [5] => elem6
    [6] => 
)
```

If you don't want the last empty element in the array, just `array_pop()` it off.

Comment: I agree, if I knew how to fix that issue I would do that first :) Perhaps you can help me take a stab at that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693128/php-build-an-array-by-looping-back-on-self-until-all-records-are-found