# PHP Build An Array By Looping Back On Self Until All Records Are Found

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have a function in PHP (using Symfony) where I am building an array by passing a value into the array first, and then I am looping through every record but changing the key/value each time until I run out of values...

For example:

I pass this value into my getFieldKeys() function listed below:

```
array(
    'fieldKey'=>'123'
);
```

Inside of this function, I first add this value to the fieldKey array and then see if there are any records that match my query...

If there are records then loop through each of those records and send the fieldKey the value back to the same function and add the value to the array...

This all works but my array look aweful. Need help cleaning up this code, not sure what to do...

```
public function getFieldKeys($array){

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $fieldKeys[] = $array['fieldKey']; // add original value to fieldKey array...

    // loop over any results and and pass key back into this same function and then do a look up on that key and repeat the process until finished...
    $keys = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:FieldKeys')->findBy([
        'fieldKey' => $array['fieldKey'],
    ]);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $fieldKeys[] = $this->getFieldKeys([
            'fieldKey'=>$key->getFieldKey(),
        ]);
    }
    return $fieldKeys;
}
```

My final array looks like this - yikes!

```
Array
(
    [0] => ccrs_date
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => prelim_title_report_date
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => additional_escrow_deposit_date
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => earnest_money_date
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => acceptance_date
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => contract_date
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What I am hoping for is something more like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => ccrs_date
    [1] => prelim_title_report_date
    [2] => additional_escrow_deposit_date
    [3] => earnest_money_date
    [4] => acceptance_date
    [5] => contract_date
    [6] => prelim_title_report_date
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you searching for `array_merge`?

Answer (score 0):

You have written a recursive function to achieve your keys array - good idea. However your function returns an array and you are adding the resulting array recursivley to the current array which causes an array nesting one down per level.

This might be what you need as your second key is always an array but you are just looking for the key:

```
public function getFieldKeys($array){

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $fieldKeys[] = $array['fieldKey']; // add original value to fieldKey array...

    // loop over any results and and pass key back into this same function and then do a look up on that key and repeat the process until finished...
    $keys = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:FieldKeys')->findBy([
        'fieldKey' => $array['fieldKey'],
    ]);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $tmp = $this->getFieldKeys([
            'fieldKey'=>$key->getFieldKey(),
        ]);
        $fieldKeys[] = reset($tmp);
    }
    return $fieldKeys;
}
```

Comment: Hm, for some reason its giving me the same result as my code above :(

Comment: Edited. How about that? Unfortunatly I cant test it

Comment: Totally understood :) Here's the error php gives me when I replace this new snippet - Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: Error gone with the new snippet?

Comment: Yeah the error is gone, the issue now is its stopping adding elements after [0], [1] then everything gets popped off. I think I can work with this though - thanks!

Comment: Without testing its not easy to guess the solution however I think the basic problem with the nesting is understandable now?